# Show that the vector $\vec{F} = (−\rho \cos{\phi}, \rho \sin\phi , z\cos\phi)$ is irrotational only when $\phi = 0.$

Tags: calculus, vectors

> Show that the vector $\vec{F} = (−\rho \cos{\phi}, \rho \sin\phi , z\cos\phi)$ is irrotational only when $\phi = 0.$

Since $\vec{F}$ is irrotational $\nabla\times \vec{F}=0$ then I got $\sin(\phi)=0$ but $0\leq \phi\leq 2\pi$ can't say irrotational only when $\phi = 0.$ Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: Do you mean that $\phi\lt 2\pi$? Otherwise, $\vec F(2\pi)=\vec F(0)$.

Comment: @JohnDouma What happen if $\phi = \pi.$

Comment: The signs on the first and third components would be reversed because the sine is still zero and $\cos\pi=-1$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Is it wrong $\phi=0, \pi$?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't compute it. I just noticed that if the vector was irrotational at $\phi=0$ then it should also be irrotational at $\phi=2\pi$. Also, are you in spherical coordinates? Should the $z$ in the third component of the vector be $\rho$?

Comment: No I am in Cylindrical polar coordinates !!

Comment: @ALMEra If you are using cylindrical coordinates, then $$\vec F=- \hat \rho \rho \cos(\phi)+\hat \phi \rho \sin(\phi)+\hat z z\cos(\phi)$$If you interpreted $\vec F$ as $$\vec F=- \hat x \rho \cos(\phi)+\hat y \rho \sin(\phi)+\hat z z\cos(\phi)$$then you are not using cylindrical coordinates appropriately. So, what are you doing??

Comment: @MarkViola I am beginner in calculus. I don't know much about this. Where am I wrong? I choose cylindrical coordinates as $\vec{f}$ has $(\rho,\phi,z)$ but the problem doesn't say anything about it?

Comment: @MarkViola I didn't interpret as what you did. I used  formula of Curl in cylindrical coordinate system

Comment: I am trying to clarify whether you have the components of $\vec F$ as you've written them are Cartesian components expressed as functions of $\rho$, $\phi$, and $z$ OR if they are cylindrical components.

Comment: @MarkViola I used $\vec{F}$ in cylindrical coordinates 1st method in your above comment

Comment: @MarkViola I used $ \vec{F} =-\vec{\rho}\rho \cos(\phi)+\vec{\phi} \rho\sin(\phi)+\vec{z}z \cos(\phi)$

Comment: What you have done is correct and yes $\phi = \pi$ is a solution.

Comment: @MathLover thank you very much